# How do I rearrange an equation to be in terms of a specified variable with Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I can write, for example,

```
Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation()
```

to generate an equation of a line that passes through those points, but the output is given as

```
-6x - 5y - 2
```

presumably being equivalent to `-6x - 5y - 2 = 0`. How can I instead set the output to be

```
y = (-6/5)x - (2/5)
```

I thought it might have to do with some formatting settings in the `equation()` method, so I checked [the documention](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html), but it didn't say anything about it.

**EDIT 1:** It appears that if I input

```
solve(Eq(Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation()))
```

I will get the (albeit ugly) output

```
⎡⎧     5⋅y   1⎫⎤
⎢⎨x: - ─── - ─⎬⎥
⎣⎩      6    3⎭⎦
```

This does give a rearranged solution, but the issue is that this is only in the form of `x=f(y)`. I'm not sure how I would get it to instead be in terms of `y=f(x)`.

**EDIT 2:** I think this might actually be a bug with `solve()`, or `Eq()`. If I instead manually type

```
solve(-6*x-5*y-2,y)
```

or

```
solve(Eq(-6*x-5*y-2),y)
```

I will get the (somewhat ugly, but correct) output of

```
⎡  6⋅x   2⎤
⎢- ─── - ─⎥
⎣   5    5⎦
```

Now if I were to instead type

```
solve(Eq(Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation()),y)
```

or

```
solve(Eq(Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation()),x)
```

I get the output of

```
[]
```

This is rather strange, though, because

```
Eq(-6*x-5*y-2)
```

and

```
Eq(Line(Point(3,-4),Point(-2,2)).equation())
```

both output

```
-6⋅x - 5⋅y - 2 = 0
```

so I'm really not sure what Is going on here.

Comment: Looks like `solveset` is the method to use see https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html

Comment: @balmy That doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: It's a comment. If I had a solution I might create an answer, although frankly I'm less inclined now given the warmth of your comment. Anyway why have you discounted it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to pass the symbol you want to solve for, you can do something like this (Although the [equation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html#sympy.geometry.line.Line2D.equation) function expects strings )

```
x, y = symbols('x, y')
eq = (Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation(x,y))

print(solve(eq, y))# prints [-6*x/5 - 2/5]
```

or you can get the symbol from the expression and pass it to solve like

```
eq = (Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation())

print(solve((eq), list(eq.atoms(Symbol))[1])) # prints [-6*x/5 - 2/5]
```

Comment: Interesting, It appears that my mistake is not passing `x,y` to the `equation()` method. This is strange behaviour, though, since `Eq()` will return the exact same equation object wether or not `x,y` is present in the `equation()` method.

Comment: Yeah from the documentation the function signature looks like this `equation(x='x', y='y')`

Answer (score 0):

The symbols used in the equation have assumptions on them and that makes them different from the plain symbols you might create with `Symbol('x')`. So that's why it has the option to pass in the symbols you want to use for `x` and `y`.

```
>>> var('x y')
(x, y)
>>> Line(Point(3,-4), Point(-2,2)).equation(x,y)
-6*x - 5*y - 2
>>> Eq(y, solve(_, y)[0])
Eq(y, -6*x/5 - 2/5)
```

That's also why you didn't get a solution in one of your examples -- the variable you were solving for wasn't in the equation. It *looked* the same but it wasn't since it had different assumptions on it.